# Ruby regex: operator and

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an string of an email that looks like `"<luke@example.com>"`
I would like to use regex for deleting `"<"` and `">"`, so I wanted something like

```
"<luke@example.com>".sub /<>/, ""
```

The problem is quite clear, `/<>/` doesn't wrap what I want. I tried with different regex, but I don't know how to choose `<` AND `>`, it is there any and operator where I can say: "wrap this and this"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your regex matches the literal substring `"<>"` only. You need to use `[]` to make them a character class so that they're matched individually, and `gsub` to replace all matches:

```
"<luke@example.com>".gsub(/[<>]/, "") # => "luke@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"<luke@example.com>".gsub /[<>]/, ""
```

http://regex101.com/r/hP3sY2

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever want to strip the < and > from the start and end *only*, you can use this:

```
'<luke@example.com>'.sub(/\A<([^<>]+)>\z/, '\1')
```

Comment: Email addresses will never contain `<>` inside them, that isn't a valid email.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need, nor should you use, a regex.

```
string[1..-2]
```

is enough.